# Play framework 1.2.4: NullPointerException in the constructor of play.exceptions.MailException

Tags: java, playframework

The problem is the following:

When sending a mail in webapp running on `Play framework 1.2.4` exception with following stack trace can be observed in logs:

```
Execution exception 
NullPointerException occured : null 

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException 
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231) 
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at play.exceptions.MailException.<init>(MailException.java:27) 
        at play.libs.Mail.buildMessage(Mail.java:79) 
        at play.libs.Mail.send(Mail.java:35) 
        at play.mvc.Mailer.send(Mailer.java:347) 
        at play.mvc.Mailer.sendAndWait(Mailer.java:355) 
        at notifiers.Mails.forgotPassword(Mails.java:19) 
        at controllers.PasswordReset.requestPasswordReset(PasswordReset.java:102) 
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548) 
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502) 
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478) 
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473) 
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161) 
        ... 1 more
```

The relevant part here is following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at play.exceptions.MailException.<init>(MailException.java:27)
```

which indicates that `NullPointerException` was thrown from constructor of `play.exceptions.MailException` (in 27th line). Source code of this constructor looks like the following:

```
public MailException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    StackTraceElement element = getInterestingStrackTraceElement(cause);
    if(element != null) {
        ApplicationClass applicationClass = Play.classes.getApplicationClass(element.getClassName());
        sourceFile = applicationClass.javaFile.relativePath(); // this line is 27th and NPE is thrown from here
        source = Arrays.asList(applicationClass.javaSource.split("\n"));
        line = element.getLineNumber();
    }
}
```

So either `applicationClass` local variable or `javaFile` property is null. Could someone familiar with `Play framework` weird internals advise what can cause this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance

### EDIT after `Seb Cesbron` answer

We also inspected `play.libs.Mail.buildMessage(Mail.java:79)` where it is clearly seen that `from` address is null, but after fixing that, similar exception popped up:

```
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.exceptions.MailException.<init>(MailException.java:27)
    at play.mvc.Mailer.send(Mailer.java:349)
    at play.mvc.Mailer.sendAndWait(Mailer.java:355)
    at notifiers.Mails.forgotPassword(Mails.java:19)
    at controllers.PasswordReset.requestPasswordReset(PasswordReset.java:102)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
```

And there, `play.mvc.Mailer.send` method contains nearly 200 lines of code enclosed in `try-catch` block, so it got really tricky to find out what was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Line 79 in Mail.java refers to a throw MailException because there is no from address.

The NullPointerException in MailException seems to show that there is no file associated to your mail. Are you sure that the file Mails/forgotPassword.html (or txt) exists ?

Comment: Please see relevant edit - we also encountered similar exception after fixing `from` address. Concerning file `Mails/forgotPassword.html/txt` - we will check this now - thanks a lot for pointing to this!

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, `Mails/forgotPassword.html` exists. It looks like the problem is with play non-standard classloading mechanism ...

Comment: you need to put a breakpoint on Mailer line 349 because this line corresponds to a rethrow, you can then know the cause exception. Can you also put a breakpoint on MailException line 27 to see which element is null

Comment: The problem is that exception occurs in `Production` environment where it's not possible to use debug. We are currently thinking on how this can be solved taking into account our limitations.